# Why i am not able to see a decimal output after division in c++

Tags: c++

Im just trying to take an average of the students marks that has entered for N number of students. I have used float also tried with double data type for `mu` variable but when i divide two integers `sum` of marks and total number of students `n` if i input the values say `n=4` and those student marks as `1,2,3,4` total `sum` is 10 so now to calculate `mu` is `10/4` i should ideally get `2.5` but i am getting `2`. I think im missing something here. I am using Ubuntu to run the program written

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int stddiv,n,a[600],i,sum=0;
    float mu = 0;
    
    cout << "Please enter the number of students"<<std::endl;
    cin>>n;
    
    for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the marks of student "<<i<<std::endl;
        cin>>a[i];
        
    }
    
        for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++)
        {
            sum=sum+a[i];
        }
        
    mu = (sum/(n));
    
    cout << "sum is "<<sum<<std::endl;
    cout << "mu is "<<mu<<std::endl;
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You divide an `int` by an `int` so the result is automatically an `int`. You assign it to a `float` after that, but it is too late, the answer is already truncated. Cast one of the `int`s to a `float` before you do the division, to force the division to result in a `float`.

Comment: Yep, thanks @yksisarvinen I was trying to find a good duplicate.